VBA SaveAs - Recent intermittent 0kb output files & code crash
We use a lot of VBA automation for client report generation tasks. These processes have been running in some cases for years, and have not changed.
In the last few weeks, there have been intermittent (but still frequent, given the volume of tasks that run through them - multiple times a day) instances of files produced by these processes having 0kb filesize, no content, and the code seemingly just... stopping on that line.
This issue is occurring for multiple teams with similar automation setups, not just in one specific implementation. Occurs in multiple areas of code, with multiple target file types (xlsx, txt). The specific lines of code are as simple as:
        Workbooks(strOverlay).SaveAs Filename:=strSaveFolder & strSaveFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

or
        For i = 0 To UBound(platformPath)
            DoEvents
            tempDataBook.SaveAs Filename:=platformPath(i) & dataName, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
            DoEvents
            tempIndxBook.SaveAs Filename:=platformPath(i) & indxName, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
            DoEvents
        Next i

(the 'DoEvents') calls are a recent addition based on a random comment somewhere of someone having a similar sounding problem recently saying it improved things, but no luck for us...)
The second example is relevant, as you can see it is simply 2 save commands back to back, with nothing else in between. From inspection, when it is the first file that is saved as 0kb, there is no second file, indicating it does not move past that line of code at all but exits the function (they are also saved with .creating on the end and then renamed, and this renaming also of course does not happen).
Log files show that it doesn't seem to pass any specific error back as part of this.
Appreciate there isn't a huge amount to go on here, but given this is now occurring across multiple processes on multiple machines that have been running without this error for years, and it being intermittent - simply throwing the same file back through will generally see it work 2nd time round - is pretty hard to diagnose beyond 'has something changed in a recent update?'. No obvious reports of similar issues have appeared in my googling, so turning to StackOverflow to see if anyone is experiencing similar, or has suggestions for how to try to prevent this!

Welcome to the board.  First thing I'd do is check that the platformPath(i) & dataName variables are returning the correct information.  I wouldn't trust the user to let me know - maybe use some code that exports the information to a text file so you can check after the event if you're not there to personally see it go wrong.

Also your tempDataBook and tempIndxBook seem to be saving in the same location with the same name - surely one is overwriting the other?

Thanks both. There is no user input at all - the names are constructed based on input filenames (which are all standardized) and certain parts of the content (which is again standardised, and there is plenty of error handling around for files that don't have the right formats to stop it getting to this bit).
Regarding the 2 workbooks - they do save to the same location, but with different names (largely the same, one with a DATA suffix and one with and INDX suffix) so no overwriting occuring.

Is maybe also worth adding that we do get a file, so we know it has the right name/path etc, just that it seems to have left behind the content somewhere!

As you are getting the file the problem must be earlier in the process - as you say, no content to save? Is the correct sheet the active one in the workbook at the point you are saving it? Are the Users able to interact with the workbook at all and if so are they "clicking around" (perhaps a new employee, which would explain why this changed recently)

Afraid not - these are fully automated processes, there is no user interaction at all as they run on service accounts on protected environments.
I don't think it is the case that it's earlier in the process and is just saving 'what it has', for 2 reasons: as mentioned, we run hundreds of things through this and it will work for the majority, and for those it fails on simply dropping the file back into the input folder makes it run through successfully.
and #2, the code clearly stops running on these failed saves lines as they do not get renamed, so seems the save itself is the issue.

You may verify there are contents in the source document with FileLen function

Is the output file being saved to a cloud location like OneDrive? this could explain the intermittent performance if the link to the cloud is overloaded or has recently changed provider.
